# building a testpage with user-customizable linq-to-sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I need to show the database tables to a tester. For now, I have hard coded the queries that show the data of each table: the user clicks on a list of tablenames and the server returns a gridview with all the data for that table. The queries are pretty simple:

```
var AllTheTable = (from t in MyDataContactTableName
                   select t).ToList();
```

I want to add a textbox where the tester can enter a custom linq-to-sql query at runtime.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a login on SQL server with read only access to the tables he/she needs, and install SQL Management Studio Client tools? Probably easier, unless this tester wants to write LINQ queries for some specific reason

Comment: Often we give the tester Management Studio and give them read-only access to specific database tables. Actually, we create a database role for testers, and put each one in that group. How much trouble are you supposed to go to to help testing? Write them an entire new app?

Comment: You could also show him LINQPad: http://b.roozz.com/apps/61/LINQPad.htm

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks for the concept; I think I'll try with Management Studio and give them access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq doesn't work like SQL- you need to run linq-to-sql queries through the compiler, because they are ultimately compiled C# code.  Why not just give your users the ability to run a SQL query?  There are a lot of security pitfalls around what you are asking either way, but with just SQL they can only mess up your database.  With linq-to-sql they could potentially compromise your web server.

If this is an internal project where security isn't a concern and you just want to give the tester arbitrary access to your SQL data, have them write SQL.

Comment: Security is not an issue; I'll use Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not reinvent the wheel and show him LINQPad :)

http://b.roozz.com/apps/61/LINQPad.htm

[image: LINQPad example]